# How to use jQuery in ASP.NET 4 master pages

Tags: jquery, exception, asp.net-4.0, master-pages, vsdoc

I have an ASP.NET 4 web app.
I am using a Master Page Site.Master.
The head of the master page is:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js">
</script>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Currently in the content page, I have:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<% if (false)
   { %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<% } %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Welcome jQuery !");
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Blam() { alert("Welcome jQuery !"); }; </script>
```

My content Page must show an alert when a button "ViewButton" is pressed!
i,e, the ViewButton must call function Blam!
How do I do that??

If I run this code, I get an exception:

readyBound is not defined!

The exception is in file: jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js
The call stack is:
          bindReady JScript
    ready   JScript
    JScript global code JScript

Comment: Is this an ASP control or a "traditional" HTML control? You may have to reference the control's `ClientID`.

Comment: @SLaks  I get the exception at $(document).ready

Comment: @Brad the Button is ASP control.
It looks like: 
<asp:Button ID="ViewRunsButton" runat="server" Text="Show Runs" OnClick="ViewRunsButton_Click" OnClientClick="Blam" />

What changes shall I do?

Comment: Try, in your code behind, binding the function (like so: `this.ViewButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return Blam();")`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't include `jquery-1.4.4-vsdoc.js` in your actual site; it is not meant to be functional.

Visual Studio should automatically read that the `vsdoc` when you include `jquery-1.4.4.js`.
Alternatively, you can include the `vsdoc` inside an `if (false)`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to include the vsdoc file on your web page - it just needs to be in the same folder as your jquery file and just provides intellisense for Visual Studio.